# How do I suppress error and output log files in SGE

Tags: cluster-computing, qsub, sungridengine

I'm running code in a Sun Grid Engine batch system that generates large log files. I can choose the output locations using the -o and -e options, but would like to know if I can tell it not to record the output at all.

Answer (score 5):

Just specify `/dev/null` for both `-e` and `-o`.